# Untangle dictionary inside list

Tags: python, json, django, mongodb, pymongo

I need some help figuring out this complicated list. I am trying to print just the `var_names`.

I have created a list from a mongo collection so that I can use it as a jSON object later.

List format:

```
[{
'tags': 
    {'variables': 
        [{'value': '3x5', 'var_name': 's'},
         {'value': '12:00AM', 'var_name': 'x'},
         {'value': 'abc', 'var_name': 'y'}]
    }
}]
```

Expected Result:

```
s
x
y
```

Please help. I keep getting errors no matter what combinations I try to get the value

Comment: try using `for var_dic in list[0]['tags']['variables']: print(var_dic['var_name'])`

Comment: You have tried _every_ possible combination? What about `x = [val.get('var_name') for val in list_obj[0]['tags']['variables']]`?

Answer (score 0):

Since the mongo collection itself and the contents of the `variables` key are both lists, I suggest iterating over them, unless you have a specific reason to address them by their index directly.

For example:

```
mongo_result = [{
    'tags': {
        'variables': [{
            'value': '3x5',
            'var_name': 's'
        }, {
            'value': '12:00AM',
            'var_name': 'x'
        }, {
            'value': 'abc',
            'var_name': 'y'
        }]
    }
}]

for obj in mongo_result:
    for var in obj['tags']['variables']:
        print(var['var_name'])

# s
# x
# y
```